# Cannot start oracle database: multiple errors

Tags: database, oracle, database-connection, startup

I have 3 oracle dbs installed on server as separate user. All three were working properly until server reboot. After which i wasn't able to start database and i am not able to execute any other command.

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Oct 26 04:53:30 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> shutdown abort
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup mount
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
SQL> shutdown abort
ORA-24324: service handle not initialized
ORA-01041: internal error. hostdef extension doesn't exist
SQL> startup
ORA-24324: service handle not initialized
ORA-01041: internal error. hostdef extension doesn't exist
```

sql querires give:

```
ERROR:
ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE
```

And connecting to sqldeveloper gives

```
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
01034. 00000 -  "ORACLE not available"
*Cause:    Oracle was not started up. Possible causes include the following
           - The SGA requires more space than was allocated for it.
           - The operating-system variable pointing to the instance is
           improperly defined.
*Action:   Refer to accompanying messages for possible causes and correct
           the problem mentioned in the other messages.
           If Oracle has been initialized, then on some operating systems,
           verify that Oracle was linked correctly. See the platform
           specific Oracle documentation.
Vendor code 1034
```

How to startup database and to recover data. I am able to start listener using lsnrctl start. And it is working fine.

alert log file::

```
Sun Oct 16 06:00:01 2016
Begin automatic SQL Tuning Advisor run for special tuning task  "SYS_AUTO_SQL_TUNING_TASK"
End automatic SQL Tuning Advisor run for special tuning task  "SYS_AUTO_SQL_TUNING_TASK"
Sun Oct 16 06:00:16 2016
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 203
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 1 seq# 202 mem# 0: /home/oracle/data/datafiles/db/redo01.log
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 203 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 2 seq# 203 mem# 0: /home/oracle/data/datafiles/db/redo02.log
Sun Oct 16 18:05:38 2016
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 204 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 3 seq# 204 mem# 0: /home/oracle/data/datafiles/db/redo03.log
Mon Oct 17 02:00:00 2016
Clearing Resource Manager plan via parameter
Mon Oct 17 06:00:04 2016
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 205 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 1 seq# 205 mem# 0: /home/oracle/data/datafiles/db/redo01.log
Mon Oct 17 22:00:00 2016
Setting Resource Manager plan SCHEDULER[0x3003]:DEFAULT_MAINTENANCE_PLAN via scheduler window
Setting Resource Manager plan DEFAULT_MAINTENANCE_PLAN via parameter
Mon Oct 17 22:00:00 2016
Starting background process VKRM
Mon Oct 17 22:00:00 2016
VKRM started with pid=21, OS id=29144 
Mon Oct 17 22:00:00 2016
Begin automatic SQL Tuning Advisor run for special tuning task  "SYS_AUTO_SQL_TUNING_TASK"
End automatic SQL Tuning Advisor run for special tuning task  "SYS_AUTO_SQL_TUNING_TASK"
Mon Oct 17 22:00:28 2016
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 206
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 1 seq# 205 mem# 0: /home/oracle/data/datafiles/db/redo01.log
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 206 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 2 seq# 206 mem# 0: /home/oracle/data/datafiles/db/redo02.log
Mon Oct 17 22:30:25 2016
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 207 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 3 seq# 207 mem# 0: /home/oracle/data/datafiles/db/redo03.log
Tue Oct 18 02:00:00 2016
Clearing Resource Manager plan via parameter
Tue Oct 25 11:22:27 2016
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D566CD, {empty}] [flags: 0x8, count: 2]
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D53DAD, {empty}] [flags: 0xA, count: 3]
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D53DAD, {empty}] [flags: 0xA, count: 4]
Tue Oct 25 14:40:20 2016
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D566CD, {empty}] [flags: 0x8, count: 2]
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D53DAD, {empty}] [flags: 0xA, count: 3]
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D53DAD, {empty}] [flags: 0xA, count: 4]
Tue Oct 25 14:53:23 2016
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D566CD, {empty}] [flags: 0x8, count: 2]
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D53DAD, {empty}] [flags: 0xA, count: 3]
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D53DAD, {empty}] [flags: 0xA, count: 4]
Tue Oct 25 15:10:00 2016
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D566CD, {empty}] [flags: 0x8, count: 2]
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D53DAD, {empty}] [flags: 0xA, count: 3]
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D53DAD, {empty}] [flags: 0xA, count: 4]
Tue Oct 25 15:34:28 2016
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D566CD, {empty}] [flags: 0x8, count: 2]
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D53DAD, {empty}] [flags: 0xA, count: 3]
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D53DAD, {empty}] [flags: 0xA, count: 4]
Wed Oct 26 01:49:06 2016
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D566CD, {empty}] [flags: 0x8, count: 2]
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D53DAD, {empty}] [flags: 0xA, count: 3]
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D53DAD, {empty}] [flags: 0xA, count: 4]
Wed Oct 26 01:49:34 2016
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D566CD, {empty}] [flags: 0x8, count: 2]
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D53DAD, {empty}] [flags: 0xA, count: 3]
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D53DAD, {empty}] [flags: 0xA, count: 4]
Wed Oct 26 03:17:52 2016
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D566CD, {empty}] [flags: 0x8, count: 2]
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D53DAD, {empty}] [flags: 0xA, count: 3]
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D53DAD, {empty}] [flags: 0xA, count: 4]
Wed Oct 26 04:01:42 2016
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D566CD, {empty}] [flags: 0x8, count: 2]
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D53DAD, {empty}] [flags: 0xA, count: 3]
Exception [type: SIGBUS, Non-existent physical address] [ADDR:0xEC8910] [PC:0x6D53DAD, {empty}] [flags: 0xA, count: 4]
```

Edit: (addition) 
Everything is properly set and it was working properly before server reboot. It was working from 3+ months and i have started and shut off database many times. All was working well until this time.

Comment: Really hard to suggest something based on this error alone. There might be millions of reasons for this error, especially when you run several instances on one server(not very good for many reasons). At this point I would only suggest disabling automatic startup(if you have configured one) for all your instances, reboot the server, verify that all environment variables are set properly, and attempt to start one instance at a time starting with `no mount`

Comment: No automatic startup set on server. Server is test server that's why multiple instances. Unable to start with nomount also.

Comment: Can you provide the complete version of these three databases ? According to the My Oracle Support this is due to bug.

Comment: You might try asking this at dba.stackexchange.com.  It will likely be closed here because it's off-topic.

Comment: Is there a way to move question there or i have to repost?  @DCookie

Comment: Complete version of database meaning? I have one database server oracle 11g with 3 dbs.

Comment: Sorry, @Akshit, if there's a way to move it I don't know of it.

Comment: @Akshi: Complete database version with patch level(For example: 11.2.0.4)

Comment: `Is there a way to move question..` yes. it needs to be closed as off-topic with "belongs to dba.stackexchange" option selected by people who have privilege to do so.

Answer (score 0):

As others suggest, this is too broad an issue to easily answer. Off-hand, it looks like your unix environment is not correct for the database(s) in question. As a minimum, ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID need to be set. The databases need proper initialization files defined, etc, etc.

Comment: Everything is properly set and as mentioned in post, it was working properly before server reboot. It was working from 3+ months and i have started and shut off database many times. All was working well.

Comment: Have you run some memory diagnostics on the server? Assuming absolutely no other changes, the Tuesday crash (and log) suggests a hardware problem.

Comment: I will run that. But meanwhile is here a way to recover data from shut off database so i can try to fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guide:
http://www.tecmint.com/oracle-database-11g-release-2-installation-in-linux/

It guides you through a good installation of Oracle on CentOS or you can find what you need to resolve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
your trouble is due to many thing like 
   -*invalid configuration reason why your have to set ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID
   -*invalid setting reason why your have to be sure that your oracle database instance is running up 
~~~~sql
set ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID
check if your database instance is running up, in case of misunderstanding check (this)[https://www.tecmint.com/oracle-database-11g-release-2-installation-in-linux/]
~~~~
```

Comment: While this code might provide an answer to the question, an explanation of how it solves the issue is recommended. Please update the answer with some explanation of how and why this code solves the issue.